# How to swap Login for Logout after a user logs in using Zend_Navigation?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I'm using an XML config file to populate my navigation using Zend_Navigation.

I have Login and Logout in the navigation, but obviously I should only display the 1 action that makes sense.

I believe I can do something like $navigation->removePage() but... How do I get the $navigation variable in a Controller after it was previously created in Bootstrap.php?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the ACL's to grant "guests" access to the login resource, and "users" access to the logout resource?

Comment: Sounds like a great idea.  Can you please share the code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create ACL with apropriate privilages for logged and not logged users, then in config file:

```
resources.navigation.pages.login.resource = "user"
resources.navigation.pages.login.privilege = "login"
```

(this is the ini format for simplicity, you may do this in XML as well)

Privilages will limit displaying login/logout links for specified group.

However…
This is good for static navigation labels.
I'd like to have login link named: `Login`, and logout named: `Logout (+ username)`, so the user sees his identity all the time.

In this case I'd create a front controller plugin which retrieves actual navigation container, finds login page container and replaces label and route (or URI or module,controller and action if you are using MVC page containers).

**Updated:**

Try something like this:

```
if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
    Zend_Registry::set('role',
    Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read()->role);
} else {
    Zend_Registry::set('role', 'guest');
}

$this->_acl = new My_Model::Acl;
$this->_auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->registerPlugin(new Plugin_AccessCheck($this->_acl));

$view->navigation()->setAcl($this->_acl)->setRole(Zend_Registry:get('role'));
```

Comment: I added <resource>user</resource> and <privilege>logout</privilege> to the navigation.xml config file, but I'm not sure how to tie the rest of this together.

I have my Zend_Acl code in the init() method of IndexController.php (not even sure if that's the appropriate place).  Can you please share the code required to accomplish this?

Comment: Perfect!  I put that code in a _initAcl() method in Bootstrap where I configured my addRole(), addResource(), allow() and deny() accordingly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zend_Application, setup Zend_Navigation as a resource (see the link on how to set your pages in your configuration file )

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html

Then you can access the navigation resource in a controller like so:

```
 class FooController extends Zend_Controller_Action
  {
      public function init()
      {
          $bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');
          $navigation = $bootstrap->getResource('navigation');
          // ...
      }
  }
```

Comment: I was able to get the nav in my IndexController from $this->view->Navigation(); ... but I'm still unsure how to associate the Login and Logout actions with Zend_Acl appropriately, so that only Login is available at first and then only Logout is available once the user has logged in.